# Compare values of two columns

Tags: mysql, select, sql-like

Is there a way to compare the values of two columns in MySQL? For example if I have a table:

```
+----------------+
| Col1  | Col2   |
|----------------|
| abc   | 123abc |
| def   | 234def |
|       | 123ghi |
+----------------+
```

And I wanted to retrieve all the entries in `Col2` that contained the values of `Col1`:

```
+---------+
| NewCol  |
|---------|
| 123abc  |
| 234def  | 
+---------+
```

How would I go about that?

Here is a pseudo-query to explain a bit further.

```
SELECT Col2 FROM TableName WHERE Col2 LIKE Col1;
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`LOCATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate)

```
WHERE LOCATE(Col1, Col2);
```

It returns a non-zero value if `Col1` is contained within `Col2`.

#### Update

Note that an empty substring is always contained within another string, so in this case you need another condition:

```
WHERE LENGTH(Col1) AND LOCATE(Col1, Col2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Col2 FROM TableName WHERE Col2 in(SELECT Col1 from TableName);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Col2 FROM TableName WHERE Col2 LIKE Concat("%",Col1,"%");
```