# How to compare values of text columns from the same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table in which each column represent a text from a manuscript, here is a simple example:

```
mss1  | mss2  | mss3
------------------------
The   |  The  |  A
big   |  big  |  big
black |       |
dog   |  dog  |  dog
```

I would like to display rows where two columns have different values (or the same values), for instance I want to see the differences between mss1 and mss3. The result should look like:

```
mss1  | mss3
---------------
The   |  A
black |
```

These seemed to be good solution candidates :

```
SELECT mss1, mss3 FROM table WHERE mss1 != mss3;

SELECT mss1, mss3 FROM table WHERE mss1 NOT LIKE mss3;
```

However it is not working, even after converting all columns from text to varchar of the same length.

I also tried LOCATE ([See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22601073/compare-values-of-two-columns)) to find same values: if I can locate mss1 in mss3 and vice-versa, they must have the same value, right? But that was not successful either.
Any idea? It seems like it should be easy, but I can't figure it out...

Comment: The first query you mentioned should work fine actually.

Comment: So what do you get when you try the first query?  How is it "Not working?"

Comment: It returns just every row in my table, and the opposite (mss1 = mss3) returns no row.

Comment: @Ely: then the the values in the rows are different; likely there's extra non-displayable characters in one or the other (most likely suspects are newline `\n`, carriage return `\r`, and tab `\t`. Also note that inequality comparison to NULL value will return NULL, not TRUE. The NULL-safe comparison operator (`<=>`) is a convenient way to get equality comparison between NULL values, e.g. `WHERE NOT ( mss1 <=> mss3 )`

Comment: @Ely: You could use the `HEX` function as a way to "dump" the column contents for a closer inspection.  `SELECT HEX(mss1), HEX(mss3)`. If the two values are not equal, then the hex representations will not be equal, and you can look for the actual difference; again, most likely it's a non-display character. (It's also possible, but much less likely, that the columns are defined with different charactersets and/or there's a characterset translation going on.)

Comment: @spencer7593: Thanks for the help! mss3 terminates with 0D, which should be the carriage return. So I added `LINE TERMINATED BY '\r'`when I create the table, and it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the issue with your query is that `NULL` values are filtered out.  For your purposes, I think this may do what you want:

```
SELECT mss1, mss3
FROM table
WHERE coalesce(mss1, '') <> coalesce(mss3, '');
```

Comment: This also returned every row in the table... now I wonder if something can be wrong in the values themselves? I loaded the data from a csv file, but I cannot see anything special.

Comment: This answer also returns the result which you need

Comment: @Ely . . . Can you set up a SQL Fiddle with some examples of data that should match but do not?